# Bootstrap confirmation icon not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-confirmation

I created a bootstrap confirmation for my link:

```
<a data-toggle="confirmation" data-title="Delete work order[![enter image description here][1]][1]?"
    href="##"><img src="./img/delete.png" height="15" ></a>
```

And the JS:

```
$('[data-toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
});
```

Everything is working fine, but the delete and cancel icons are not showing (image below). Why is it now showing? Is there a way to remove this icon and just display the buttons with its label?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you have the font `Glyphicons Halflings` it should be working, check your CSS files.

Comment: Got it... Font was missing. Thanks

Comment: Awesome! Have fun

Comment: Crap... I can't use onClick="myFunction(deleteID);"? It always call myFunction even though I click on cancel instead of delete. Is there a way to use onClick?

Comment: Go to the [docs](http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/#usage), you can use both `onConfirm` and `onCancel` callbacks!

Comment: Yes, I was reading it, but it will apply for all the confirmation buttons the same fucntion

Comment: confirmation will always be called, you need to set which button does what

Comment: Got it. Can I pass a parameter to onConfirm?

Comment: Yes, like the example: `onConfirm: function(value) {
    alert('You choosed ' + value);
  }`

Comment: Sorry... I asked it wrong. How can I send the value from my page to the function(value)?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but, read the docs. It's not that easy to compile in a single sentence. You might have to use Popover (if necessary)

Comment: Thanks... I'll try using singleton

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that you have all the 3 files below were included in your page.
especially the css file which contains the font.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The Image did not show because you have referenced the full links of the actual directory where it resides.

Something like this can give you a clue

```
http://localhost/project/img/delete.png
```

or you can also try adding two dots (..) to get retrieve deeper.

```
../img/delete.png
```

Mean while bootstraps has many beautiful gliphyicons that you can integrate without using images

You can try this directory with bootstrap glyphicons

```
<a data-toggle="confirmation" data-title="Delete work order[![enter image description here][1]][1]?"
    href="##">Delete <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
```

More refrences on Boostraph Gliphyicons can be found here
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp